# Entire set of order statistics

Tags: order-statistics

Let's say that we have $X_{1}$,...,$X_{n}$ iid discrete random variables (let's say that there are 15 possible values in the support of the discrete distribution) and n is a large number (let's say 50). $Y_{1}$,...,$Y_{n}$ are order statistics. Is there any way to calculate the entire set of $Y_{1}$,...,$Y_{n}$? (is it possible at all with that many variables?)

Comment: The order statistics, by definition, are the values of the $X_n$ when sorted.  That's how one "calculates the entire set."  Evidently you mean something else, but what would it be??

Comment: Let's say we have a simple case, there are two variables and each can take values 0 or 1. There are 4 combinations in total: (0,1), (1,0), (0,0) and (1,1). However, if I need to calculate values for the order statistics they are the following: (0,0), (0,1) and (1,1). I am interested how can I calculate the last set for more variables and more values in the support of a discrete distribution.

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to ask: your question asks to compute the order statistics; your comment asks to compute their sample space; but most likely you are interested in the joint distribution of the order statistics (because the first two issues are trivial).  Could you explain more?

Comment: No, I need a sample space (its dimension to be precise). I am trying to think if it's feasible to have the full list in R.

Comment: Okay, but if your numbers are as given in the question (15 and 50), your task is hopeless, because you don't have the computing power to store and compute over 100 trillion possibilities!  It's unclear what you might mean by "dimension" of the sample space: by definition,  the sample space is the set of possible values of $(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)$ and it doesn't have any dimension.

Comment: Do you want every list of 50 numbers 1-15 with the numbers in ascending order?

Comment: @Dave Because ties have positive probabilities when the distributions are discrete, the lists have to include repeating values, making $\binom{50+15-1}{15}$ possibilities.